# How to properly style an infowindow?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, infowindow

I'm trying to show the users location on the map, which works, but the infowindow has to be styled. I've tried using setInfoWindowAdapter to style the infowindow but it doesn't apply the styles.

Here is my code:

```
public void handleNewLocation(Location location){
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    mMap.clear();

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    List<android.location.Address> addresses = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker))
            .title("Uw locatie:")
            .snippet(address+", "+postalCode+" "+city+", "+country);
    Marker locationMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
    pointToPosition(latLng);
    locationMarker.showInfoWindow();

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext(); //or getActivity(), YourActivity.this, etc.

            LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(context);
            info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            TextView title = new TextView(context);
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            title.setText(marker.getTitle());

            TextView snippet = new TextView(context);
            snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

            info.addView(title);
            info.addView(snippet);

            return info;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't apply the styles" -- please explain in greater detail what you mean by this. You might wish to upload a screenshot somewhere, then link to it from your question, if allowing us to see your output would help. With respect to your choice of `Context`, please use the `Activity`. And, if this is an `AppCompatActivity`, create your layout in XML and inflate it using a `LayoutInflater` that you get from `getLayoutInflater()` on that `AppCompatActivity`, rather than create the widgets directly in Java code.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the output: http://s32.postimg.org/xcqa2li85/Untitled.png

Comment: And it has to look like this: http://s32.postimg.org/v6z9yaamd/Untitled.png

Comment: Um, well, your code is set up to deliver the results from the first screenshot. It is doing so successfully, from what I can tell. What specific problems are you encountering when trying to write the code to deliver the results from the second screenshot? Why do you think that "it doesn't apply the styles"?

Comment: I'm having problems adding enters between the lines, I cant go to a new line in a snippet. I'm not sure on how to get the background of the window blue and transparent and how to color the text properly.